# Use vue load component asynchronously with webpack?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I want to load a big component asynchronously speed up the loading speed.My idea is roughly as follows：

```
<template>
    <div class="code-wrapper">
        <div v-if="loading">loading...</div>
        <big-component v-else></big-component>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        loading:true
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      //request <big-component> asynchronously here
    }
  }
</script>
```

How to implement the async component with code splitting of webpack?

Comment: Have you tried following [this section in Vue's guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components) that's explicitly about using async components with webpack's code-splitting feature?

Comment: @jingman I have followed the [guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components) and find the way to use async components with webpack's code-splitting feature.Howerver, is there any way to be aware of the loading state of the  async components? Because I want to show a spinner when loading and remove it when loaded.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know how to answer that, so I did some digging. [This codepen](http://codepen.io/sirlancelot/pen/NNdyWJ) seems to be _exactly_ what you want. The commented-out part of the JS code is an example of how yours should look. Basically you just use a `require('./bigComponent.vue', resolve)` when you're defining the component. You might do something like...
`components: {
  bigComponent (resolve) {
    require(['./bigComponent.vue'], bigcomp => {
      this.loading = false
      resolve(bigcomp)
    })
  }
)`
note: this is completely untested and probably wrong ^